# How do I display all taxons/categories AND all products for each on the category page in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Take a look at [this site's top taxon page](http://livegoodinc.com/t/category).

As you can see, all taxons/categories are listed, with products under each. However, only 4 products max are being displayed on this page. To verify that there are more products for these taxons, click on one of the 3 sub-category links on the left or under the breadcrumbs.

What I'd like to accomplish, is to display all products for each category, all on one page. So far I have tried changes to the products and taxons controllers and views, with no difference.

I have also set the per_page param to a high number, and stepping through the code I see that the **retrieve_products** method on the ***Spree::Search::Base*** class actually returns 17 product records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out:

The TaxonsHelper module has the taxon_preview method, which gets called by the taxon partial, which in turn gets called by the show view for taxons.

This method accepts a limit on how many products to display per taxon, which defaults to 4. The param name is max.

I will look into setting this value in a cleaner way, or maybe making sure it uses the per_page param, but for now I'm just going to pass in the max value of 24 or something.